# Creating a First-time chrome extension for video sites to remove ads (to remove class using get element by ID)

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

Creating a First-time chrome extension for third party video sites to remove particular classes using get element by ID and It runs or remove automatically when the same element appears from that website like Adblock do.

When the video page refreshes or loads the first time then no problem occurs (the ID finds the value) code run successfully but when the video end and auto-plays another video in sequence (from the playlist) without refreshing the website.
Then the problem arises. I start getting a null value when trying to get an element by Id or Undefined when clicking the button.

```
var temp =  document.getElementById('html5_player_id_html5');
 alert('Element temp : ' + temp);
```

**Result: Null**

```
var v = document.getElementsByClassName("ad-point");
  alert('Element temp : ' + v[0]); 
  while (v.length >0) v[0].remove();
  alert("Hello timetext remove");
```

**Result: Undefined**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var link = document.getElementById('btn_click_id');
  // onClick's logic below:
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {     alert("Hello Butteon click ");
   window.onload = myFunction();
  });
});   

function timedText() {   setTimeout(myTimeout, 1000) }

function myTimeout()
{ 
  var v = document.getElementsByClassName("ad-point");
  alert('Element temp : ' + v[0]);       
  while (v.length >0) v[0].remove();

  alert("Hello timetext remove");
}

function myFunction()
{
  // event.preventDefault();
  let temp = document.getElementById('html5_player_id_html5');
  alert('Element temp : ' + temp);          
  
  if(typeof(temp) != 'undefined' && temp != null)
    {
        temp.remove();
        console.log("3 Hello Html5 d4d chrome extenstion : " +  temp);
        alert('Element exists!');          
        timedText();
    } 
  else
   {
      if(typeof(temp) == 'undefined' && temp == null)
          {
           alert('Element null value!');   
           timedText();    
          }
            else{
                  // myFunction();
                  timedText();    
                  alert('Element does not exist!');
                }
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Viki Launcher</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <link
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <style>
      /* Modal Structure */

      html,
      body {
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: 0;
        min-height: 180px;
        padding: 0;
        width: 260px;
      }

      h1 {
        font-family: "Menlo", monospace;
        font-size: 22px;
        font-weight: 400;
        margin: 0;
        color: #2f5876;
      }

      a:link,
      a:visited {
        color: #000000;
        outline: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      img {
        width: 10%;
      }

      .modal-header {
        align-items: center;
        border-bottom: 0.5px solid #dadada;
      }

      .modal-content {
        padding: 0 22px;
      }

      .modal-icons {
        border-top: 0.5px solid #dadada;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .logo {
        padding: 16px;
      }

      .logo-icon {
        vertical-align: text-bottom;
        margin-right: 4px;
      }

      .version {
        color: #444;
        font-size: 18px;
      }

      .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 10px 22px;
      }

      .flex {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
        width: 80px;
      }

      .flex:hover {
        opacity: 0.4;
      }

      .flex .fa {
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #2f5876;
      }

      .separator {
        width: 100%;
        border-top: 2px groove white;
        margin: 5px -5px 5px -3px;
      }

      #titletext {
      padding: 8px 8px 2px 0px;
      text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="popup.js"></script> -->
    
  </head>

   <body >
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h1 id="#titletext" class="logo">
        <!-- <img class="mainlogo-icon" src="images/iconsd4d.png  " /> -->
        <img class="logo-icon" src="images/icons.png " /><b> Viki</b> Ads
        <span class="version">(1.0.0)</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <p>If you've DANCE content would like to share, just send a DM/TAG US on instagram <b>@dance4dancerss</b> & we post it. 
        Featuring dancers from around the world <i class="fa fa-globe" style="color:rgb(248, 75, 44) "></i> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-icons">
      <div class="flex-container">
        <!-- <div class="flex">
          <a href="https://www.traversymedia.com" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-globe" style="color:darksalmon "></i>
          </a>
        </div> -->
        <div class="flex">
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_WvEJntnJM" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-youtube" style="color:rgb(248, 75, 44) "></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <a href="https://www.twitter.com/dance4dancers" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter" style="color:rgb(248, 75, 44) "></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dance4dancerss" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-instagram" style="color:rgb(248, 75, 44) "></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <a href="https://facebook.com/dance4dancers" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook" style="color:rgb(248, 75, 44) "></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div></div>
        <div id="separator0" class="modal-header"> 
      </div>
        <button class="btn_click" id="btn_click_id">Click</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[You can see below images when I run in the console it shows me data but when I run in editor it shows me null or undefined when I get value from ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcqbk.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcqbk.png)

I searched it throughout the day today but didn't get any information anywhere.
Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8ORr.png)

Comment: firstly, `Result: Undefined` is expected, since you've removed all those elements, so `v` will be empty - secondly, if `document.getElementById('html5_player_id_html5')` returns `null` that means there's no element with that id - should there be, since you removed it, why would it re-appear except if the page is reloaded

Comment: Also, `typeof(temp) == 'undefined'` can never be true, since `document.getElementById` never returns `undefined`

Comment: thank you or your response @JaromandaX  but when the current video end then second video play/load from the playlist the element reappears again (for me it's like the page content reloads rather than a whole web page load).
Please go through the images I uploaded you can see when I run the individual statements in the console it runs successfully but when I try to run in the editor it creates the problem.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF4w0.png]

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpUY5.png]